# solution for complex number equation with power

Tags: complex-numbers

i have the following equation $$z^3 = 2 + 2i$$
and I need to find the solutions of this equation in trigonometric form.
how do I find multiple solutions of such an equation?

Comment: Put $2+2i$ in the form $re^{i\theta}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $2+2i=2\sqrt2e^{i\pi/4}=2^{3/2}e^{i\pi/4}$

So $z^3=2^{3/2}e^{i\pi/4}\implies z=\sqrt2e^{i\pi/12}\omega$, where $\omega$ is a 3rd root of unity.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** $2+2\mathrm i=2^{\tfrac32}\mathrm e^ {\tfrac{\mathrm i\pi}4}$.

Answer (score 2):

write the number $2+2i$ in the form $2\sqrt2e^{i\pi/4}$.

Answer (score 2):

$$z^3=2+2i$$
$$z^3=|2+2i|e^{\arg(2+2i)i}$$
$$z^3=2\sqrt{2}e^{\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{2}{2}\right)i}$$
$$z^3=2\sqrt{2}e^{\tan^{-1}(1)i}$$
$$z^3=2\sqrt{2}e^{\frac{\pi}{4}i}$$
$$z=\left(2\sqrt{2}e^{\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+2\pi k\right)i}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}$$
$$z=\sqrt{2}e^{\left(\frac{1}{12}\pi  +\frac{2}{3}\pi k\right) i}$$

And k goes from 0-2 -> $k=0-2$ and k is the element of Z. So: